# IE 11 shortcut to Google search bar

Tags: shortcuts, internet-explorer-11, google-search

We use IE 11 for work and I just want to know if there's a shortcut to get to the Google search bar after duplicating the tab. It doesn't focus in the bar when I duplicate the tab using (CTRL + K).

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a shortcut? When you open www.google.com the focus is **already in the text box**

Comment: Then use the <tab> key as many times as is needed.

Comment: I edited my post. That is the search bar I meant.

Comment: For me (IE11 on Win7), if I'm looking at a Google search result page (as in your picture), the box doesn't appear focused, but it is (unless another on-screen input box has been given focus) -- just start typing.

Comment: It's after I duplicate a tab. What I do is a search for something and then duplicate it so I can type something else.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Doesn't work if the OP has **duplicated** the tab.

Comment: Cntrl-T then Cntrl-E?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know/can find, there are no shortcuts for Google's search results page. At least not currently (there was some experimental ones, but those seem to have gone away since they were reported in like 2012).

> It's after I duplicate a tab. What I do is a search for something and then duplicate it so I can type something else.

I would suggest that instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to duplicate the tab, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to duplicate it.  That way IE duplicates it to a new tab, but leaves you on the original tab, so you can perform more searches (the box retains focus).

Comment: No problem, glad it helps. :)  Please take note for the future: Center your questions about the actual problem (can't type in box after duplicating tab), instead of (only) asking about a supposed solution (shortcut to box).  'Cause really the answer to your question is simply "There is no shortcut", which wouldn't help you with your actual problem.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to avoid the XY problem. I edited the question to make it more clear, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

#### I just want to know if there's a shortcut to the Google search bar?

1. Click somewhere in the body of the page
2. Press <kbd>escape</kbd> to return to the search bar.

Or:

1. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> 11 times

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: For option 1, step 1: that defeats the purpose of the shortcut though.

Comment: <shrug> I couldn't find a better solution :/

Comment: No problem. Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's suggestion works fine for me.